# Virtaualbox-5.1/5.2 not working in ubuntu-17.04?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-17.04

Hello I'm facing problem in starting virtualbox-5.1/5.2 in ubuntu 17.04.

```
virtualbox
```

Here is the error during starting VM

VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed:

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are trying to use a 32 bit version on a 64 bit system

Comment: The versions are Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit and virtualbox-5.2_5.2.2-119230_Ubuntu_zesty_amd64 both are 64-bit. It may be something other.

Comment: is visualization enable on your BIOS? Or have you a more detailed error ?

Answer (score 0):

Charlie Lutaud The versions are Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit and virtualbox-5.2_5.2.2-119230_Ubuntu_zesty_amd64  both are 64-bit. It may be something other.